# Long-term hiking journey across the EU/Schengen - complex visa query

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, eu-citizens, long-stay-visas, brexit

My partner and I are planning a hiking/backpacking trip from the UK, through France, Belgium, Netherlands, Germany, Denmark to Norway - Knivskjellodden (with a really tiny short-distance hike in Sweden, due to the lack of willingness to climb). We plan to do this in the future, maybe in 2 or 3 years, depending on various circumstances.

We both live in the UK permanently and legally. I am a citizen of an EU country, but she is a native British citizen. She will need a visa (I will potentially need one too, for part of our trekking in Norway - we plan to walk through Norway for 150-170 days, and then travel back to the UK).

Which visa/visas shall we apply for, in both circumstances (married and not-married)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that 150-170 days in Norway alone, or does it include getting there as well? Because that would add a significant amount of time.

Comment: That would be 150-170 days in Norway (aside from a distance of about 13 km or so in Sweden, in the area of Rago Naional Park), as obviously all of the trekking from the UK is a rather long-distance trip (a trekking through Europe to get onto the ferry in Denamrk to get to Norway would take us minimum 50 days with a maximum of 70 days; we suspect about 60-65 days in total, before even reaching Norway)

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming here that the main issue is the long stay in Norway, and that the rest is short (less than 90 days), so there are no issues for that part since she is both a UK citizen and the family member of an EU citizen.

So there are two steps:

- You, as a EU citizen, have the right to live, work and study in Norway. Since this stay exceeds 3 months, you need to register [here](https://www.udi.no/en/want-to-apply/residence-under-the-eueeu-regulations/). In you case, you would probably be in the "[EU/EEA national with own funds](https://www.udi.no/en/want-to-apply/residence-under-the-eueeu-regulations/eueeu-national-who-has-their-own-funds/)" category. Registration is free, must be done within 3 months of your arrival, and there are a few conditions attached (sufficient funds, health insurance...).
- Your partner, as a family member of a EU citizen, can stay for up to 3 months without a visa or permit, but will need to apply for a [Residence card for family members of EU/EEA nationals](https://www.udi.no/en/want-to-apply/family-immigration/residence-card-for-family-members-of-eueea-nationals-/). You do not need to be married, though marriage or a civil partnership could make it easier in terms of documentation.

If you are in an unregistered domestic partnership:

> You must meet one of the following two requirements:
>
> - You must have lived together for at least two years and neither of you can be married to someone else.
> - You have, or are expecting, a child together. You are both unmarried or divorced.

Then in the first case you have to provide (in addition to the usual passports, etc.):

> - documentation showing that you have lived together the last two years, for instance tenancy agreement, sales contract or a registration of residence
> - confirmation (no older than six months) from public authority in the home country on the marital status of the applicant and reference person, or notarially certified self-declaration (affidavit) if public authority does not issue such confirmation (no older than six months)
> - if the applicant or the reference person has been married before: divorce certificate or death certificate. As a main rule the divorce should be registered in the same country as the marriage was entered into

(applicant = your partner, reference person = you)

You also need to answer a dozen or so questions about your relationship. More details [here](https://www.udi.no/en/checklists-container/family/eos/checklist-for-residence-card-for-cohabitant-of-eueea-national-/?c=gbr).

You can apply for the card while in Norway or from the UK.

Comment: Could OP travel to the UK after 89 days, and then back to Norway to finish his journey? (I'd expect not, but was just wondering)

Comment: @Berend no, because that would defeat the whole point of a long-distance trekking that have been planned, alongside with a 180-day rule that is a requirement for a 90-day visa (*her not his)

Comment: @ShibaInu666 This was more of a hypothetical question, I wasn't saying you should (or shouldn't) do that.

Comment: I understand, it is just an explanation of the circumstances :) Plus, the 180-day rule does exclude the possibility to return to the UK to continue the trek straight afterwards (alongside with it being very enviormentally unsustainable)

Comment: @ShibaInu666 90/180 rule for short stays do not apply to EU citizens and their family members exercising freedom of movement. Even if you do not register, there is no problem immigration wise (you might get a fine for failure to register, but it does not affect your rights to stay and move in the EU). In practice, a marriage or recognized partnership makes a *much* simpler process.

Comment: @xngtng the value of a marriage or durable partnership is not only practical.  Unregistered "durable partners" are in a different legal position from spouses and registered partners because they fall under article 3(2) of directive 2004/38/EC rather than 3(1).  Member states aren't required to recognize their rights of free movement before the relationship is "duly attested."